# Setup Quart server with HTTP/2

Tags: google-chrome, http2, quart

I am trying to setup a Quart server to play with HTTP/2. I have been trying to go through the minimal documentation at:

- https://gitlab.com/pgjones/quart

Where I have:

```
$ cat app.py
from quart import Quart, render_template, websocket

app = Quart(__name__)

@app.route("/")
async def hello():
    return await render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/api")
async def json():
    return {"hello": "world"}

@app.websocket("/ws")
async def ws():
    while True:
        await websocket.send("hello")
        await websocket.send_json({"hello": "world"})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5001)
```

Some basic check:

```
$ curl -I --http2 http://acme.corp:5001
HTTP/1.1 101
date: Tue, 02 Mar 2021 10:05:12 GMT
server: hypercorn-h11
connection: upgrade
upgrade: h2c

HTTP/2 200
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length: 0
date: Tue, 02 Mar 2021 10:05:12 GMT
server: hypercorn-h2
```

Looking at the output

```
$ python3 app.py
 * Serving Quart app 'app'
 * Environment: production
 * Please use an ASGI server (e.g. Hypercorn) directly in production
 * Debug mode: False
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5001 (CTRL + C to quit)
[2021-03-02 11:01:49,083] Running on http://0.0.0.0:5001 (CTRL + C to quit)
[2021-03-02 11:01:53,011] 10.221.0.114:53637 GET / 1.1 200 0 5817
[2021-03-02 11:01:53,255] 10.221.0.114:53637 GET /favicon.ico 1.1 404 103 1348
```

Here is what I see, when I load the index.html page from chrome:

[image]

What am I missing to get http/2 from chrome ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locally you are upgrading an insecure HTTP 1.1 request to an *insecure* HTTP 2 request. This works with Quart and curl, but browsers including chrome do [not support insecure (unencrypted) HTTP/2](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2015/06/15/http2_implementation_status). For it to work in chrome I create a self signed certificate, passing the certfile and keyfile options to the run and accept the warning chrome offers when visiting the site. An example exists [here](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/quart/-/blob/master/examples/http2/http2.py#L39).